# Evaluate and combine Contiguous records in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, contiguous

Since I'm new to Spark/Scala I'm dealing with my first problems and I'd like to know if there's a simple way to approach them with Spark native operations combined with scala methods, because maybe I'm missing something.

Let's assume that I have a text file log (previously ordered) with each line representing person|time

`Peter|5:45
 Peter|6:05
 Peter|6:27
 Peter|6:58
 Peter|6:59
 Peter|7:59
 Mark|7:40
 Mark|7:55
 Mark|8:30`

Now I'm able to create an RDD storing person and time:

```
val file = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
val log = file.map(x => (x.split('|').lift(0).get,x.split('|').lift(1).get))
```

What I would like to have is a new value (interval) representing the fact that continguous records (for the same person) belong to same interval of time if their difference is lesser than 30 minutes.

In the following table you can see that:

- records #1 and #2 differ by 20 minutes so they are in the same inteval
- records #2 and #3 differ by 22 minutes so they are in the same interval
- records #3 and #4 differ by 31 minutes so they are NOT in the same interval (making #1 #2 #3 the first interval, and #4 the first record of the next interval)

```html
#   Person   Time   "Lag"     Diff      Note                   Interval
1   Peter    5:45   -         -         first row Peter        Peter started at 5:45
2   Peter    6:05   5:45      20        <30 mins               Peter started at 5:45
3   Peter    6:27   6:05      22        <30 mins               Peter started at 5:45
4   Peter    6:58   6:27      31        >30 mins               Peter started at 6:58
5   Peter    6:59   6:58      1         <30 mins               Peter started at 6:58
6   Peter    7:59   6:59      60        >30 mins               Peter started at 7:59
7   Mark     7:40   -         -         first row Mark         Mark started at 7:40
8   Mark     7:55   7:40      15        <30 mins               Mark started at 7:40
9   Mark     8:30   7:55      35        >30 mins               Mark started at 8:30
```

So my RDD should look like this:

```html
 Person   Time   Interval
 Peter    5:45   Peter@5:45
 Peter    6:05   Peter@5:45
 Peter    6:27   Peter@5:45
 Peter    6:58   Peter@6:58
 Peter    6:59   Peter@6:58
 Peter    7:59   Peter@7:59
 Mark     7:40   Mark@7:40
 Mark     7:55   Mark@7:40
 Mark     8:30   Mark@8:30
```

Is this possible with reasonable effort, or am I pretending too much from Spark native operations combined with Scala Methods?

Maybe going Spark-SQL to manipulate my dataset could be easier since I'm more familiar with SQL, but I'd like to get familiar with Spark core as well.

Every suggestion, hint, code-example will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

FF

Comment: The last step (grouping by an interval) IMO can't be done concurrently, so I doubt Spark has such method. Everything up to that step probably can. You can look at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/rdd/RDDFunctions.scala, there is a method called sliding.

Comment: After some practice I've learned how to re-create a sort of "LAG" construct using SCALA/Spark in order to "lag" my RDD.
What is still missing is the final group-by part (Coulmn Interval in the example)... it's really tricky since I have to use "vanilla SQL" inside spark-sql